# php function variable error

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to create a simple receipt for a transaction using data customer posted. All I'm getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING:

```
function receipt($transaction, $count, $product, $price, $date)
   {
   echo "You $transaction $count of $product at  $price on $date";
   }


receipt ('BOUGHT', "$_POST["itemcount"]", "$_POST["code"]", "$details["price"]", date("F j Y"));
```

I've tried adding curly braces/replacing quotes with braces, but neither approach worked.

Comment: Your IDE should have syntax highlighing and that should indicate the problem to you. As you can see, from the code you've pasted here, that there is a problem with the highlighting and hence - the syntax.

Comment: Either remove the `"` around the variables or escape them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, remove double from post value like "$_POST["itemcount"]" to $_POST["itemcount"] from all.

```
 - function receipt($transaction, $count, $product, $price, $date) {
       echo "You $transaction $count of $product at  $price on $date"; }

   receipt ('BOUGHT', $_POST["itemcount"], $_POST["code"],
   $details["price"], date("F j Y"));
```

Comment: Your post is un-readable. Please take some time to [format it correctly.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass variables as strings, remove the quotes around them:

```
receipt ('BOUGHT', $_POST["itemcount"], $_POST["code"], $details["price"], date("F j Y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the double quotes, it's working now, thanks. Always thought I needed them, string or otherwise, apparently not.

Answer (score -1):

try below

```
receipt ('BOUGHT', $_POST['itemcount'], $_POST['code'], $details['price'], date("F j Y"));
```

instead of

```
receipt ('BOUGHT', "$_POST["itemcount"]", "$_POST["code"]", "$details["price"]", date("F j Y"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function receipt($transaction, $count, $product, $price, $date)
   {
   echo "You ".$transaction." ".$count." of ".$product." at  ".$price." on ".$date."";
   }


receipt ('BOUGHT', $_POST['itemcount'], $_POST['code'], $details['price'], date("F j Y"));
```

You can also use this way to display your variables

Comment: you cant use variables normally in an echo command thats why i used ".$variable." to make them showup in the echo

Comment: I just removed the double quotes as you did without using concatenation operator in echo, echo's accepting the $variables normally. Thanks though.